# Style bootstrap checkboxes as buttons without btn-group

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I'm trying to get a list of items from my database, where each listed item is paired with a selectable button for "delete" in the Bootstrap alert style. When the user submits using a "delete selected" button at the bottom of the page, all the entries that were selected will be removed from the database.

Now, Bootstrap's [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons) only explains how to style check boxes as buttons in a `btn-group` div, which groups them all together in one line. I'm working with a list, so I don't want the checkbox buttons in a group: I need them per line, and clearly associated with the label of the entry they're deleting. But I can't seem to get the checkboxes to style as buttons without that btn-group div. It seems pretty arbitrary, and I'm wondering if there's an easy way to do this in bootstrap styling without resorting to hand-writing a bunch of javascript onclick events to use the regular bootstrap button type without checkboxes.

Here's what I have right now, where I just put every checkbox by itself in its own little btn-group, but it formats all weird and autoselects the buttons by default:

```
@foreach ($data['entries'] as $entry) <!-- blade template stuff -->
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    Label of the database entry
                    <label class="btn btn-danger active">
                        <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Delete
                    </label>
            </div>
            </br>
            </br>
@endforeach
```

Is there a good way to do this in Bootstrap, or am I stuck writing it myself in js?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#checkboxes-and-radios Is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: I would like to style the checkboxes as to appear as bootstrap buttons.

Comment: As in when it's pushed down it's selected and when it's not it's not selected? Could you show something similar to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sure, see the documentation for bootstrap above, under the single toggle or checkbox/radio sections. I'd like it to look like the single toggle, but be defined in HTML as a checkbox to make my form submission easier. The checkbox/radio section seems to do that but insists that the checkboxes must be grouped. I'm wondering if I can do it without needing to group them.

Comment: I think i get you now. So you just want a couple of buttons stacked as opposed to side by side that are toggleable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@foreach ($data['entries'] as $entry) <!-- blade template stuff -->
  <div data-toggle="buttons">
    Label of the database entry

    <label class="btn btn-danger">
      <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Delete
    </label>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

This should work, as simple as just removing the `btn-group` class

Comment: This looks better, but the buttons are still all selected by default, even though the input checkbox does not contain the `checked` attribute. Any ideas?

Comment: I amended the code, just remove the `active` class from the `<label>`